# How to skip scanning symbolic links while using Simian for duplicate code detection

Tags: simian

How to skip scanning symbolic links while using Simian for duplicate code detection?

I am currently using Simian to scan a directory for duplicate code, but I would like to skip any symbolic links in the directory to avoid redundant calculations.Could anyone please provide me with information on how to skip scanning symbolic links using Simian?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.